# Is it possible to specify the namespace prefix just once in a xpath expression?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, namespaces

I have only one namespace in my XML file, defined on the root element.

```
<root xmlns="http://my-namespace">
    <aChild>
        <secondChild />
    ...
```

**Is it possible to avoid writing it before each element of my xpath expression ?**
After doing

```
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://my-namespace");
```

I have to write

```
xml.SelectNodes("ns:root/ns:aChild/ns:secondChild", xmlNamespaceManager);
```

And it would be much easier to do just

```
xml.SelectNodes("ns:root/aChild/secondChild", xmlNamespaceManager);
```

I have developpers who send xpath expressions to the XML but they don't necessarily know the prefix or the namespace, they just know they have to access `root/aChild/secondChild`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately as intuitive as it seems, there's no easy way do define the default namespace in XPath. An XPath name without a namespace declaration binds to the `null` namespace, rather than the URI assigned to the default namespace.

This is discussed in [XPath default namespace handling](http://www.edankert.com/defaultnamespaces.html) and [Easy things should be Easy](http://plasmasturm.org/log/259/)

Answer (score 1):

you can add the namespace at document level

```
  XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  

  XmlSchema schema = new XmlSchema();
  schema.Namespaces.Add("xmlns", "http://www.sample.com/file");

  doc.Schemas.Add(schema);
```

Comment: I don't really understand how I should use my XML document to query xpath after that (with SelectNodes() for example).

Comment: after adding the schema as shoed above you don;t need specify it every time but you can do : doc.SelectSingleNode("/mynode")