# XPath to select the nodes that matches

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I have a XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RootName>
  <RandomNode v="someValue"/>
  <Series>
    <Idendity v="C16"/>
    <CodeOut v="C41073"/>
    <Period>
      <TimePeriod v="2013-07-18T22:00Z/2013-07-19T22:00Z"/>
      <Resolution v="PT60M"/>
      <Interval>
        <Pos v="1"/>
        <Qty v="14.1"/>
      </Interval>
      <Interval>
        <Pos v="2"/>
        <Qty v="20.7"/>
      </Interval>
```

And I need a xPath that returns all the `Period` nodes which matches these conditions:

- The node `CodeOut`/`CodeIn` has the value of any of the values that I have in an array
- This node `CodeOut` can be named `CodeOut` or `CodeIn`, but only one of these
- The date on `TimePeriod` must match

The only node that repeates over the xml is the `Series` node. In other words, there is only one `Period` per `Series`, but there is a lot of different `Series`.

For example, get all `Period` nodes which have his `Codeout` or `CodeIn` value to being `C41073` or `B85028` and the date being `2013-07-18`.

I tried, to match the multiple names, using something like:

```
//*[@v="C41073"] | //*[@v="B85028"] | ...
```

But I think it will be better if only matches the correct nodes, just in case some other node has the same value, isn't it?

I was searching to use something like "contains", but it works in a different way.

I'm using .Net, if that matters, and I'm going to use this xPath on the `.SelectNodes()` function.

---

**EDIT:**

Something strange is happening. Maybe the syntax is not correct. Look at this tests:

This: `doc.SelectNodes("/*")(0).Name`    is returning `RootName`
This: `doc.SelectNodes("/*/*").Count`    is returning `912`
This: `doc.SelectNodes("/*/*")(11).Name` is returning `Series`

But this: `doc.SelectNodes("/RootName").Count`  is returning `0`
This: `doc.SelectNodes("/*/Series").Count`      is returning `0`
And this: `doc.SelectNodes("/*/RootName").Count` is returning `0`

Making all the other xPath sequences suggested in answers not working.

*EDIT:*

Ok, it was the namespace, I did this:

```
Dim xmlnsManager As Xml.XmlNamespaceManager = New System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable)
xmlnsManager.AddNamespace("ns", "http://example")
```

And adding `ns:` before every element node name in the xPath sequence. (See this for more information about it: [Is it possible to specify the namespace prefix just once in a xpath expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241931/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-namespace-prefix-just-once-in-a-xpath-expression))

Comment: The value of that `v` attribute on the `TimePeriod` element does not appear to be a standard xml data type value.  I take it that's two date/time values (start time and end time) separated by a slash?

Comment: Yes, it is. What I do is a split using `/`. I dont know if its possible with xPath, im looking for it right now.

Comment: Do you have to use XPath?  Why not use Linq to XML?

Comment: Im using Net Framework 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select all of the `Period` elements limited just by the `CodeIn`/`CodeOut` list, you could do something like this:

```
/RootName/Series[(CodeOut/@v = 'C41073') or (CodeOut/@v = 'B85028') or (CodeIn/@v = 'C41073') or (CodeIn/@v = 'B85028')]/Period
```

If you don't want to list each item in the list as a separate condition, you could concatenate them all together into a delimited list and then use the `contains` function, like this:

```
/RootName/Series[(CodeOut/@v and contains('|C41073|B85028|', concat('|', CodeOut/@v, '|'))) or (CodeIn/@v and contains('|C41073|B85028|', concat('|', CodeIn/@v, '|')))]/Period
```

Notice, to avoid the problem with a substring like `C4` matching the full value, like `C41073`, you need to concatenate the delimiter before and after the attribute value.  Also, you need to make sure your delimiter exists at the beginning and ending of the delimited list of values.  Also, whatever delimiter you choose must be an invalid character which would never occur in any of the values in the list.

However, limiting it also by the `TimePeriod` will be a bit more problematic, since it appears to be a non-standard time range value.  If the start and end times were stored in separate nodes, it would be easier.

If all you need to do is match an exact `TimePeriod` value, for instance, you could just do something like this:

```
/RootName/Series[(CodeOut/@v = 'C41073') or (CodeOut/@v = 'B85028') or (CodeIn/@v = 'C41073') or (CodeIn/@v = 'B85028')]/Period[TimePeriod/@v = '2013-07-18T22:00Z/2013-07-19T22:00Z']
```

You can split the string on the `/` character, with `substring-before(TimePeriod, '/')` and `substring-after(TimePeriod, '/')`, but unless you are using XPath 2.0, you can't compare strings to see if they are greater or less than.  If you are using 2.0, you could compare each of those substrings with the search value using the `compare` function, but it's still messy.  It's probably best to handle that time-range comparison in your .NET code.

Comment: So, actually, the best option is to put every code two times? (for `CodeOut` and `CodeIn`)? And I suppose there is no such thing as `contains` to check a lot of values instead of checking every value with `OR`.

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate how the `contains` function could be used.  Honestly, though, it's a bit hacky, and not really any more elegant, so, personally, I'd just stick with the first example.

Comment: Since you are searching on two different element names, I can't think of a way to avoid listing the items twice.  Perhaps someone with more XPath expertise than me can think of a good way to do that.  If so, I'd be curious to see it :)

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to make the namespace as default and not to put `ns` (see example) on every name? Nah, founded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241931/is-it-possible-to-specify-the-namespace-prefix-just-once-in-a-xpath-expression

Comment: Yes, I actually already answered that namespace question a couple of times too, such as here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11348458/1359668